# Better explanation of Go's `select` statement?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'd like to start by saying I've watched numerous tutorials on Go's concurrency model and read extensively to try and understand what I'm missing here before posting the question but I'm not grasping something fundamental. I have this little Go program and am having trouble understanding the `select` statement. Here's the program and my understanding (or lack thereof) follows it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

var readValue = make(chan int)
var writeValue = make(chan int)

func set(newValue int) {
    writeValue <- newValue
}

func read() int {
    return <-readValue
}

func monitor() {
    value := 0
    for {
        select {
        case newValue := <-writeValue:
            value = newValue
            fmt.Printf("%d ", value)
        case readValue <- value:
            fmt.Println("Adding %d to readValue", value)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    go monitor()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for r := 0; r < 10; r++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            set(rand.Intn(100))
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("\nLast value: %d\n", read())
}
```

So my understanding of the `select` statement is that it blocks until one of its branches can execute. Looking at the program, we have two `chan int`s defined at the package level, `readValue` and `writeValue`. Now I know we can read from a *closed* channel and receive the zero value of it based on the specified type, but as these channels are both open, neither can be read from and the only lines of code that add something to the channel are in `set()` and in the second `case` of `monitor()`. The first goroutine to be instantiated is `monitor` so, to me, the second `case` statement should add `0` to the `readValue` channel right off the bat. As the anonymous goroutines begin executing and calling `set`, they put random values into the `writeValue` channel, so now both branches of `monitor`'s `switch` can theoretically execute, as `writeValue` has values in it and `readValue` can always be added to, so Go will choose one at random. But this is clearly not what happens, as I never see the log in the second `case` in the console. The actual output is:

```
87 47 81 81 18 25 40 56 0 59
Last value: 59
```

I think I'm close in my understanding but am missing something simple so I'd appreciate anyone who could shed some light on what's really happening here. Cheers!

Comment: The channels are unbuffered, so for anything to be written to them, something else must be simultaneously read from them.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely overlooked that important detail even though I just explained that concept to someone else a few hours ago. Guess it's just been a long day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> so now both branches of monitor's switch can theoretically execute, as writeValue has values in it and readValue can always be added to

this is not the case at all.The second case will only be executed when the ***readValue*** can be write to.And that happens only when you call ***read()***

Note: Conside ***select case*** as  IO-multiplexing provided by golang. without buffer space or the remote end, it is impossible to write to or read from.